# Google Fluentd Decode Base64

Tags: google-cloud-platform, fluentd

I have log file which have record between two tags `RecordStart` and `RecordEnd` the recorded message is `base64` encoded I want to decode the message using `google-fluentd` and so it can send to other services.
My Config:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path <path_ot>/metrics.log
  pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/metrics.pos
  read_from_head true
  format  multiline
  multiline_flush_interval 2s
  format_firstline /^RecordStart/
  format1 /^RecordStart\n(?<record>(\n|.)*)RecordEnd$/
  tag presto_server
</source>
```

I am not able to figure out how to decode base64  Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [filter plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter) to [decode base64](https://github.com/MerlinDMC/fluent-plugin-filter-base64-decode) files.

Your config file in this case may look like this:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path <path_ot>/metrics.log
  pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/metrics.pos
  read_from_head true
  format  multiline
  multiline_flush_interval 2s
  format_firstline /^RecordStart/
  format1 /^RecordStart\n(?<record>(\n|.)*)RecordEnd$/
  tag presto_server
</source>

<filter presto_server>
  type base64_decode
  fields mesg
</filter>
```

This is an adaptation of the config file I found [here](https://github.com/MerlinDMC/fluent-plugin-filter-base64-decode/issues/1).

You may also find this documentation helpful: [HYow to modify log records](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#modifying_log_records) ingested by `fluentd`.